# Adding new signature by reatining existing unsigned signature fields using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox, sign

I want to sign PDF which has signature fields in it already. I need to add new signature field retaining existing unsigned signature fields. After signing such PDFs, I see that  new signature field added by code is always invalid.  Says 'document has been altered'.

Below code being used to compute hash of the document:

```
private DocumentSignatureStructure createSignatureStructureAndComputeHash(byte[] inputFile, File tempFile,
                                                                              SignatureProperties sigProperties)
            throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
             PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(inputFile);
             SignatureOptions signatureOptions = new SignatureOptions();) {

            signatureOptions.setPreferredSignatureSize(SignatureOptions.DEFAULT_SIGNATURE_SIZE * 2);
            signatureOptions.setPage(sigProperties.getPage() - 1);
            if (sigProperties.isVisibleSignature()) {
                PDRectangle rect = createSignatureRectangle(doc, sigProperties);
                signatureOptions.setVisualSignature(createVisualSignatureTemplate(doc, rect, sigProperties));
            }


            PDSignature signature = new PDSignature();
            signature.setFilter(PDSignature.FILTER_ADOBE_PPKLITE);
            signature.setSubFilter(PDSignature.SUBFILTER_ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
            signature.setSignDate(Calendar.getInstance());
            doc.addSignature(signature, signatureOptions);
            ExternalSigningSupport externalSigning = doc.saveIncrementalForExternalSigning(fos);

            MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance(sigProperties.getHashAlgorithm().getAlgoName());
            byte[] hashBytes = digest.digest(IOUtils.toByteArray(externalSigning.getContent()));
            String base64Hash = Base64.toBase64String(hashBytes);
            externalSigning.setSignature(new byte[0]);
            int offset = signature.getByteRange()[1] + 1;
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(signatureOptions);
            return DocumentSignatureStructure.builder().offset(offset)
                    .hashValue(base64Hash)
                    .build();
        }
    }
```

Embedding signature code:

```
byte[] originalDocumentByte = docBlob.getBytes(1L, (int) docBlob.length());
            File file = new File(getTempFolderPath(), getTempFileName("signed"));
            try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);) {
                fos.write(originalDocumentByte);
            }
            try (RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw")) {
                raf.seek(documentSignatureStructure.getOffset());
                raf.write(Hex.getBytes(Base64.decode(encodedSignature)));
            }
            Blob signedAndLtvBlob;
            try (PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(file);
                 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                 FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)) {
                if (createDss) {
                    log.info("Adding revocation information to DSS dictionary of PDF");
                    makeLtv(doc, revocationData);
                }
                doc.saveIncremental(fos);
            }
```

It did not work with above code.

Googled up and saw few solutions where COSObject 'NeedToBeUpdated' flag needs to be set to true.
Added below code block before adding new signature fields in above code.

```
//..
if (sigProperties.isVisibleSignature()) {
                PDRectangle rect = createSignatureRectangle(doc, sigProperties);
                signatureOptions.setVisualSignature(createVisualSignatureTemplate(doc, rect, sigProperties));
            }

            PDAcroForm acroForm = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
            COSDictionary catalogDictionary = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getCOSObject();
            catalogDictionary.setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
            COSDictionary acroFormDictionary = (COSDictionary) catalogDictionary.getDictionaryObject(COSName.ACRO_FORM);
            acroFormDictionary.setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
            COSArray array = (COSArray) acroFormDictionary.getDictionaryObject(COSName.FIELDS);
            array.setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
            for (PDField field : acroForm.getFieldTree()) {
                if (field instanceof PDSignatureField) {
                    COSDictionary fieldDictionary = field.getCOSObject();
                    COSDictionary dictionary = (COSDictionary) fieldDictionary.getDictionaryObject(COSName.AP);
                    dictionary.setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
                    COSStream stream = (COSStream) dictionary.getDictionaryObject(COSName.N);
                    stream.setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
                    while (fieldDictionary != null)
                    {
                        fieldDictionary.setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
                        fieldDictionary = (COSDictionary) fieldDictionary.getDictionaryObject(COSName.PARENT);
                    }
                }
            }
            
            PDSignature signature = new PDSignature();
            signature.setFilter(PDSignature.FILTER_ADOBE_PPKLITE);
            signature.setSubFilter(PDSignature.SUBFILTER_ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
//..
```

Even this did not work.

Resulting PDF shows signature is invalid:
[image]

PDF used for signing with signature fields:
[image]

Whats the piece I am missing here?

PDF file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-vu9_WIfFo198v6AxoBMxCuyX1rE2FOS/view?usp=share_link

Signed PDF (invalid): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DD0aKVkonH9a_CfGrj9mACe6DBt4Ijsj/view?usp=share_link

Comment: Please share an example PDF signed like that for analysis.

Comment: @mkl shared PDF

Comment: Thanks, but can you please share the PDF *with the invalid signature* for analysis.

Comment: @mkl added signed PDF

Comment: Rajath, concerning my analysis of your files (see my answer below), have you found what caused the zeroing out of the two 4KB regions in your file?

Comment: Thanks for taking time on the analysis. I am not sure whats causing it.
I just signed another document without Signature fields(but with other form fields like radio, dropdown, input box etc) in PDF with same code. that signature looks good.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M0jqg5UQIcFiFkyU1jpHFDjd1BaCFtPh/view?usp=share_link

Comment: *"I just signed another document ...  that signature looks good."* - It does but that document is much much smaller than the earlier one. It's just 0xad5d bytes long while the first zeroed gap in your problem PDF starts at offset 0x2c000. You may want to test with larger files.

Comment: Furthermore, I see that your *Embedding signature code* not only embeds the signature but also has a `try` block in which a method `makeLtv` may be called and always an incremental update is stored. As you don't show the code of `makeLtv`, we cannot tell whether that code may do the damage...

Comment: Thanks for pointing out 'makeLtv' might be causing the problem.
I tried signing without making PDF LTV and it worked.
'makeLtv' is method used to add revocation info(OCSPs & CRLs) to PDF to make it LTV enabled.
Are you seeing anything which might be going in makeLtv code? below link has 'makeLtv' related code
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1smDvOhyDreM9ffaCyjNt_SqOHqFdXLj3/view?usp=share_link

Comment: I don't see anything in the shared code that may cause the zeroed gaps in the error outputs. BUT a possible problem is that in the `try` structure enclosing your `makeLtv` call, you use the same file to load the document from (`PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(file)`) and to write the result to (`FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file)`). Try to use different files there. During `doc.saveIncremental(fos)` PDFBox attempts to access the file `doc` was loaded from but in your structure creating `fos` already truncated that file. Also don't create that unneeded `FileInputStream fis`.

Comment: Thanks @mkl. I was searching for solution in wrong place while it was issue with the way streams were used to read and write file data.
Signature is valid now. Thanks.

Comment: @RajathRJoshi consider adding your own answer that explains the mistake you made, so that it can help others.

Answer (score 2):

Something indeed damaged your file, and it's apparently not the code you show.

Comparing your signed file "Formulier DSS-01 - DC+QV Onboarding Checklist-signed.pdf" with your original "Formulier DSS-01 - DC+QV Onboarding Checklist.pdf", one sees that the former is not simply the latter with incremental updates as one would expect but that some regions in that file part have been overwritten with zeros.

The regions in question are from 0x2c000-0x2cfff and 0x40000-0x40fff.

After fixing this issue by copying the contents from those regions of the original file into the signed file, Adobe Acrobat validates the signature positively.

So you should try and find out what zeroed those two 4KB regions in your file.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for mistake in code for generating hash of the document.
But the issue actually was with the way file streams were used to write CMSSignedData and adding DSS dictionary for making signing PDF LTV.

Using same File for loading and writing was causing some parts of file getting overwritten by zeros.

Below piece of code for embedding external signature solved my issue.

```java
Blob docBlob = documentSignatureStructure.getReadyDocument();                      
byte[] originalDocumentByte = docBlob.getBytes(1L, (int) docBlob.length());        
File signedFile = new File(getTempFolderPath(), getTempFileName("signed_"));       
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(signedFile)) {                    
    fos.write(originalDocumentByte);                                               
}                                                                                  
try (RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(signedFile, "rw")) {              
    raf.seek(documentSignatureStructure.getOffset());                              
    raf.write(Hex.getBytes(Base64.decode(encodedSignature)));                      
}                                                                                  
                                                                                   
File signedLtvFile = new File(getTempFolderPath(), getTempFileName("signedLtv_")); 
try (PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(signedFile);                                 
     FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(signedLtvFile)) {                 
    if (createDss) {                                                               
        log.info("Adding revocation information to DSS dictionary of PDF");        
        makeLtv(doc, revocationData);                                              
        doc.saveIncremental(fos);                                                  
    }                                                                              
}                                                                                  
                                                                                   
Blob signedAndLtvBlob;                                                             
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(signedLtvFile)) {                   
    signedAndLtvBlob = new javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob(fis.readAllBytes()); 
}                                                                                  
                                                                                   
Files.delete(signedFile.toPath());                                                 
log.debug("temp signed file {} deleted successfully", signedFile.getName());       
Files.delete(signedLtvFile.toPath());                                              
log.debug("temp ltv signed file {} deleted successfully", signedLtvFile.getName());
return signedAndLtvBlob;
```